# How to use withResponsiveFullScreen on a Material-UI Dialog

Tags: material-ui

I'm using the prelease of Material-UI were you can use Grid Layouts and implements breakpoints. I've already used the components hidden and grid, now I want to use withResponsiveFullScreen component of a Dialog. The problem is I don't know how to use it and the oficial page just give a little explanation.

I can use Hidden in order to change beetween two diferent dialogs, but I prefer not to duplicate my code in that way. So is there someone who knows how to use it?. I just want the Dialog to be fullScreen at xs breakpoint.

I'm constructing my dialog using an extended class of React.Component and returning at render() a Material-UI Dialog with my own content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I know how to use `withResponsiveFullScreen`. You have to use it directly to the Dialog Material-UI class and then use the returning component to create your dialog.

Here and example:

```
var ResponsiveDialog = withResponsiveFullScreen()(Dialog);
class MyDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){ super(props); };

    render(){
        return (
            <ResponsiveDialog>
                <DialogTitle></DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent></DialogContent>
            </ResponsiveDialog>
        );
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Don't use withResponsiveFullScreen inside render function.

To change the breakpoint just pas and object with the breakpoint:

```
var ResponsiveDialog = withResponsiveFullScreen({breakpoint: 'xs'})(Dialog);
```